# Extracting word embeddings for a xlnet calssification model in simple transformers?

Tags: nlp, simpletransformers

I am trying to implement a xlnet transformer model using the Simple Transformers library. I am following this particular tutorial - https://simpletransformers.ai/docs/multi-class-classification/

According to this, I can train the model on the train_df and then produce results like accuracy, f1 score, etc. but is there a way to extract the word embedding produced by this model when trained on the training data? I would be interested in analyzing the plotting those embeddings for academic purposes but I am unable to figure out a way to do so in the Simple Transformers library.

Comment: try the hugging face library and another point to remember is transformers give you the embedding of the tokens for out of vocabulary words, you don't get the embeddings of the entire word every time.  You have XLNETforSequenceClassificationModel in hugging face